# ShellScript for retornar valores do banco cada valor em 1 variavel diferente?

Tags: if, while, shell, else, unix

Olá estou tentando retornar 1 valor para cada variavel consigo retornar porem, estou tentando criar uma condicao que valide com um for quais são verdadeiras e quais sao falsas e me exiba na tela poderiam me ajudar? abaixo meu codigo.

```
read numero
vartest1=`psql -X -A -d database -U usuario -h host1 -t -c "select telefone from tabela where numerodiscado = '$numero' limit 1;"`
vartest2=`psql -X -A -d database -U usuario -h host2 -t -c "select telefone from tabela where numerodiscado = '$numero' limit 1;"`
vartest3=`psql -X -A -d database -U usuario -h host3 -t -c "select telefone from tabela where numerodiscado = '$numero' limit 1;"`
vartest4=`psql -X -A -d database -U usuario -h host4 -t -c "select telefone from tabela where numerodiscado = '$numero' limit 1;"`
clear


ap1='t'
ap2='t'
ap3='t'
ap4='t'

for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
do
echo "${vetor[$i]}"
if [ $ap1 == "$vartest1" ]; then
       echo "Telefone Localizado Ap1"
     else
             echo "Não Telefone Localizado Ap1"
       sleep 1
if [ $ap2 == "vartest2" ]; then
          echo "Telefone Localizado Ap2"
               else
             echo "Não Telefone Localizado Ap2"


    if [ $ap3 == "vartest3" ]; then
           echo "Telefone Localizado Ap3"
                else
             echo "Não Telefone Localizado Ap3"


    if [ $ap4 == "vartest4" ]; then
        echo "Telefone Localizado Ap4"  
             else
             echo "Não Telefone Localizado Ap4"  
fi
done
```

Quando executo, apenas a 1 condição é validada, no caso ap1 sempre é true como poderia fazer uma cadeia de ifelse onde validaria independente da posição no caso comparia a ap1,ap2,ap3,ap4 se uma dessas fosse verdadeira me retorne na tela, caso todas sejam falsas me retorne na tela não estou conseguindo testar todas elas poderiam me ajudar.

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar o While `while [ condition ]
do
   command1
   command2
   command3
done` ? ou seja, crie duas condições while, uma para verificar os verdadeiros e outra para os falsos. Ou entao apenas um IF-ELSE, Se verdadeiro, echo verdadeiras, Senao echo falsas.

Comment: Consegui criando o while muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após pesquisar e errar bastante consegui criar um while que atenda minha necessidade.

```
while [[ "$vrx" == "$num5"  ]] || [[ "$vrx" == "$num6" ]] 
do
if [ $vrx == $num5 ]; then
  echo "Telefone $numero  - Status: Está Inativo"
  sleep 1
  ativa
elif [ $vrx == $num6 ]; then
  echo "Telefone $numero - Status: Está Ativo"
  sleep 1
  ativa
else
   echo "Telefone não Encontrado"
  sleep 1
  aclp
fi
done
```

Obrigado a todos dos stack pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

É mais fácil usar o While: `while [ condition ] do command1 command2 command3 done` 
ou seja, crie duas condições while, uma para verificar os verdadeiros e outra para os falsos. Ou entao apenas um IF-ELSE, Se verdadeiro, `echo verdadeiras`, Senão `echo falsa`.